# Getting file from private storage problem Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, download, storage

I'm trying to pull files from the private storage in laravel 5.7

I just can't get the file.

```
return Storage::download('/app/storage/download/' . 'file1.txt');
```

This is the error

```
File not found at path: app/storage/download/file1.txt
```

Any thoughts on problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: Make sure file should be there.

Comment: show how to store a file

Comment: I needed to update my storage_path($path)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my
storage_path($path)